# Otra forma de guardar archivos sin xp_cmdshell SqlServer 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Buen día compañeros, necesito su ayuda, tengo un `storedprocedure` donde se ejecuta un `select` y la información que obtiene de esa consulta me la imprime y guarda como un archivo `.txt`en una ruta específica por medio del comando `xp_cmdshell`. Lo que me gustaría hacer es realizar la misma acción de guardar la información en un archivo pero evitando el comando `xp_cmdshell` ya que por temas de seguridad no debo usarlo, les dejo partes del script:

```
SET @output ='\\SERVERPRO\PaymentsReport\REPORTE_TRX__MYREPORT.txt'

SET @cmd = 'SELECT Pagos FROM dbo.Pagos'

SET @cmd = 'sqlcmd -S MYSERVER -E -Q ' + '"' + @cmd + '"' + ' -o' + @output + ''  
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @cmd, NO_OUTPUT
```

Si me pueden proporcionar un ejemplo se los agradecería de antemano. Gracias y saludos.

Comment: ¿Puedes usar `Ole Automation Procedures`? en ese caso podría sugerirte una solución.

Comment: Un consejo puede ser, que lo hagas desde una aplicación en el lenguaje que desees, para así con tu Query llene tu archivo txt o cualquier otra extensión. Espero te sea de ayuda Saludos!!!

Comment: No se exactamente que sea "Ole Automation Procedures", pero es una alternativa que podría considerar en caso de que genere un archivo .txt con el resultado de un select al momento de ejecutar un StoredProcedure.

Comment: Puedes utilizar un SSIS Package para esto e inclusive con mas opciones. Necesitaras crear un par de conexiones y lo puedes tambien automatizar en un job de SQL Server si es necesario. Aqui podras encontrar un tutorial sencillo. https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/integration-services/lesson-1-create-a-project-and-basic-package-with-ssis?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo único que se me ocurre que puedes intentar hacer desde un SP solo con TSQL es  aprovechar el acceso a los `Ole Automation Procedures` (siempre que el servidor tenga configurada esa posibilidad) e instanciar un objeto `Scripting.FileSystemObject` para aprovechar la función `WriteLine`.

En primer lugar, habría que verificar y eventualmente reconfigurar el servidor para que permita este tipo de procedimientos:

```
-- Para ver la configuración (1=On)
EXEC sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures';  

-- Si nos devuelve un error es por que no está habilitado el acceso a las
-- configuraciones avanzadas. Para habilitarlo:
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;

-- Para configurar los Ole Automation Procedures
EXEC sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1; 
RECONFIGURE;
```

Teniendo configurado correctamente el servidor, el siguiente es un ejemplo conceptual de la solución: queremos exportar el resultado de una consulta sencilla: `SELECT id,name FROM SYSOBJECTS` a un archivo, lo que haremos es:

- Usar un cursor que apunta a una consulta
- La consulta retornará una sola columna que se corresponderá con cada línea del archivo, hay que convertir los datos que hagan falta a `VARCHAR` y formatear todo como queremos que vaya al archivo.
- Recorremos el cursor e invocamos el método `WriteLine` para escribir cada línea

---

```
DECLARE @FS         int 
DECLARE @OLEResult  int 
DECLARE @FileID     int 
DECLARE @FileName   VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @Registro   VARCHAR(MAX)

-- Es compatible con UNC ej \\server\carpeta\archivo.txt
SELECT  @Filename = 'c:\Salida.txt'

EXECUTE @OLEResult = sp_OACreate 'Scripting.FileSystemObject', @FS OUT 
EXECUTE @OLEResult = sp_OAMethod @FS, 'OpenTextFile', @FileID OUT, @FileName, 8, True 

DECLARE Registros CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY
FOR SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,id) + ',' + name
    FROM SYSOBJECTS

OPEN Registros
FETCH NEXT FROM Registros 
INTO @Registro

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN  
    EXECUTE @OLEResult = sp_OAMethod @FileID, 'WriteLine', Null, @Registro
    FETCH NEXT FROM Registros 
    INTO @Registro
END 

EXECUTE @OLEResult = sp_OADestroy @FileID
EXECUTE @OLEResult = sp_OADestroy @FS

CLOSE Registros
DEALLOCATE Registros
```

Si quieres evitar el uso del CURSOR, deberías guardar todo en una sola variable y salvar esta:

```
EXECUTE @OLEResult = sp_OACreate 'Scripting.FileSystemObject', @FS OUT 
EXECUTE @OLEResult = sp_OAMethod @FS, 'OpenTextFile', @FileID OUT, @FileName, 8, True 

SELECT @Registro = ''   
SELECT @Registro = @Registro + CONVERT(VARCHAR,id) + ',' + name + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13)
    FROM SYSOBJECTS

EXECUTE @OLEResult = sp_OAMethod @FileID, 'WriteLine', Null, @Registro
EXECUTE @OLEResult = sp_OADestroy @FileID
EXECUTE @OLEResult = sp_OADestroy @FS
```

#### Importante:

Ten en cuenta que esto es un hueco de seguridad un poco menos peligroso tal vez que el de un `xp_cmdshell`, pero sigue siendo un hueco, por lo que cabe la posibilidad que si no te dejan usar uno tampoco te dejen usar el otro.

Comment: Hola que tal Patricio, gracias por tu respuesta. Disculpa, ¿Existe otra manera de hacerlo sin utilizar cursores?

Comment: @BDOM, si, eventualmente podrías concatenar todas las líneas con un salto de línea en cada una, todo en un sola variable y guardar la misma, pero eso tiene una limitación en el tamaño de un `VARCHAR(MAX)`. Verifica mi última edición.

Comment: Disculpa @Patricio Moracho, tengo un inconveniente ya que al ejecutar el script que me compartiste no veo que me cree el archivo en la ruta especificada (uso la misma ruta que tu, incluso con UNC intenté). ¿Se debe a que @ Registros no tiene datos?, en ese caso ¿Coloco mi consulta dentro? Ej.: SELECT @ Registro = 'select top 10 * from pagos'. Gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: @BDOM, creo que no tienes clara la idea, debes construir tu la linea a salvar, `@Registro` o la variable que llames tiene que representar la linea completa correspondiente a una única fila de tu `select`. Por ejemplo: `SELECT @Registro = CONVERT(VARCHAR, ColumnaNumerica) + ',' + ColumnaVarchar + ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, ColumnaFecha, 111) FROM ...`. Si te fijas, estoy agregando hasta las comas de separación, si listas este `SELECT`  debiera retornarte una sola columna.