# Exportar tabla Sql Server a un archivo CSV o TXT a traves de un Procedimiento Almcenado

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, stored-procedure

Recurro a uds(mis conocimientos son vagos en SQLServer), ya que a través de un procedimiento almacenado, necesito generar un archivo CSV o txt con los datos de una tabla CLIENTE, donde como parametro le pase una fecha(nacimiento), y me devuelva todos los clientes que nacieron en esa fecha.

```
RUTCLIENTE|NOMBRE|FECHANACIMIENTO
XXXXXXXXXX|JUAN  |05-03-1990
XXXXXXXXXX|LUIS  |05-03-1982
XXXXXXXXXX|ANA  |05-03-1965
```

Favor su apoyo.

Comment: Eso se puede hacer con bcp. Si lo quieres hacer desde SQL Server, necesitas tener acceso al procedimiento xp_cmdshell.

Comment: A través de un SP que contenga un cursor no es posible?.

Comment: Los SPs no tienen acceso directo al sistema de archivos. Para eso usamos xp_cmdshell e invocamos bcp desde ahí.

Comment: Agradecido por la ayuda Luis.

Comment: Otra forma podría ser esta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/185840/otra-forma-de-guardar-archivos-sin-xp-cmdshell-sqlserver-2008/186151#186151

Comment: Es interesante, pero demasiado problema desde mi punto de vista y generaría casi el mismo conflicto que permitir el uso de xp_cmdshell. Al menos hay ejemplos de ambas opciones ahí.

Comment: Gracias Patricio.